# website in webview Xamarin Forms upload file

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have my MainPage.xaml with my webview:

```
 <WebView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Navigating="OnNavigating" Navigated="OnNavigated" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="loadVideo_wv"  />
```

in my MainPage.xaml.cs i load link:

```
loadVideo_wv.Source =link;
```

I add permission in my manifest to read files but when i want to upload a file, i have this:

```
[EGL_emulation] eglMakeCurrent: 0xd661a300: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd660ff80)
```

[eglCodecCommon] setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 0 0
[EGL_emulation] eglMakeCurrent: 0xd661a300: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd660ff80)
[chromium] [WARNING:spdy_session.cc(3180)] Received WINDOW_UPDATE for invalid stream 9
[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Unrecognized feature: 'payment'.", source: https://js.stripe.com/v3/ (1)
[chromium] [WARNING:spdy_session.cc(3180)] Received WINDOW_UPDATE for invalid stream 9
[chatty] uid=10147(com.sqinteiro.locnwork) Chrome_IOThread identical 1 line
[chromium] [WARNING:spdy_session.cc(3180)] Received WINDOW_UPDATE for invalid stream 9

How can i resolve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These message seems can be ignored, can you upload file successfully? In addition, you can try some other website with the webview.

Comment: Nop, normally i have js prompt "success" but in my webview i am redirected to index page or maybe webview is reloaded.

Comment: But there is no error in the logcat, did you enable the javascript and DomStorage in your Android renderer?